# Android XML SAXParser handling ampersand from URL?

Tags: android, xml, sax

I am parsing XML from URL using SAXParser. The XML has some data with ampersand (&) sign. XML data is not read after the ampersand. How would I resolve this issue?

```
URL website = new URL(FullURL); 
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
HandlingXMLStuff doingwork = new HandlingXMLStuff();
xr.setContentHandler(doingwork);
xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));    
String information = doingwork.getInformation();
```

XML tag has data like

```
<choice>Cat &amp; Dog</choice>
```

I am getting output as

```
Cat
```

Comment: I'd say that snippet isn't valid XML and SAX is very lenient not to throw an exception. You can't have a "naked" ampersand in XML, it should probably be `<choice>Cat &amp; Dog</choice>`.

Comment: Frustrating nonetheless. You might look into XmlPullParser.  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 0):

To have a naked '&' rather than "&amp;" you need to use a CDATA[[]] structure around the "Cat & Dog".